# TabLayout visual bug: gray transparent strips on both sides

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tablayout

There are two transparent vertical strips on both sides of my TabLayout. It looks like this:

[image: app screenshot]

It appeared after I removed `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"` from TabLayout, because it didn't show TabLayout indicator:

[image: app screenshot]

What might be the issue?

My layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="my.beeline.kz.ui.ScrollableController">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:titleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_margin"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:tabMinWidth="120dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/gray_solid"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_very_light"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Update:

Solution was to remove `android:background="@null"` from AppBarLayout

Comment: Check my answer I have updated my answer

Comment: Try to add app:tabMode=”fixed” in your view, might be the problem is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me I hope it worked for you :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue, those stripes still visible

Comment: Problem was that i added android:background="@null" for AppBarLayout, as was stated in one performance guide (to remove overdraw). But you helped a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm going to show you how to implement material design tabs in your android app.

**1. Open build.gradle of app level and add design support library because TabLayout is a part of Android Design Support Library:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

**2. Add Tab layout and View pager in you layout `activity_main.xml` or wherever you willing to add**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="fixed">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

**3. `app_bar.xml` for toolbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
app:title="@string/app_name"/>
```

**4. `style.xml`**

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme"
parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
 <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
 <item name="titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

- *Some options to customize tabs appearance:*

`app:tabGravity=”fill”` for Navigation tab gravity. Other is the centre for placing navigation tabs from centre

`app:tabIndicatorColor=”@color/white”` for an indicator in tabs. Here you can see the white indicator.

`app:tabIndicatorHeight=”4dp”` for indicator height.

`app:tabMode=”fixed”` for tab mode. Other is scrollable for many more tabs.

`app:tabTextColor=”@color/semi_yellow”` for unselected tab text color.

`app:tabSelectedTextColor=”@color/yellow”` for selected tab text color.

If you want to add icons to tab, you have to do is call setIcon() method of the tab. Create icon array and assign each one for each tab like this:

**Tabs with the icon:**

```
private int[] tabIcons = {
 R.drawable.home,
 R.drawable.notification,
 R.drawable.star
};
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
```

*And the time of Result:*

[image]

Without icon

[image]

**Happy Coding!!!**

Comment: The question is about those two gray stripes, this answer didn't provide any info about that.

Comment: You can implement with this steps to solve your problem, and I’ve mentioned few properties at the end, which are helpful you to resolve your problem